# Поочередный вывод массива по нажатию

Tags: php, sql

Пишу систему тестирования. В базе данных в 1 строке имеется вопрос, список ответов, правильный ответ и id самого теста. Как реализовать вывод каждой строки по нажатию на кнопку? Реализован только просто вывод значений, а как поочередно сделать? Буду благодарен

**База данных**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**PHP обработчик**

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM `questions` WHERE `id_test` = :id_test");
$sth->execute(
    [
        ':id_test' => $_GET['id_test']
    ]
);
$array = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

**HTML**

```
            <form action="test.php" method="POST">
            <?php
            foreach ($array as $val) {
            echo '
        <div class="form-check">
              <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="exampleRadios" id="exampleRadios1" value="option1" checked>
              <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios1" name="q1">
                '.$val['ans1'].'
              </label>
              <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios1" name="q2">
                '.$val['ans2'].'
              </label>
              <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios1" name="q3">
                '.$val['ans3'].'
              </label>
              <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios1" name="q4">
                '.$val['ans4'].'
              </label>
              
            </div>
            ';
            }
            ?>
```

Comment: а что вы делать будете, если вдруг понадобится не 4 варианта ответов сделать, а 5 ?

Comment: @teran, Предусмотрено только 4 варианта ответов

Comment: в форме надо передавать номер текущего вопроса, и выбирать в запросе следующий.

Comment: @teran, Благодарю